# How can I get font path from resources in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resources

I have spring boot app. In `resources/static` I have font `CyrilicOld.TTF`

How can I get path to this font?

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/static/CyrilicOld.TTF";
```

or

```
public static final String FONT = "/static/CyrilicOld.TTF";
...
 BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, false, null, null, false);
```

I get error

java.io.IOException: resources/static/CyrilicOld.TTF not found as file or resource.

if `BaseFont.createFont(this.getClass().getResource("/static/CyrilicOld.TTF").getPath(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, false, null, null, false)`

error

```
com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Table 'name' does not exist in /C:/gitProjects/BillingInvoiceGenerator/target/classes/static/CyrilicOld.TTF
```

Comment: is the font file actually in `/C:/gitProjects/BillingInvoiceGenerator/target/classes/static/` ?

Comment: I have this font in resources/static/CyrilicOld.TTF

Comment: I asked you to check the given file with complete path. Maybe it doesn't get copied from resources to the target folder

Comment: Can someone still solve this